# Is it possible to get each thread's `comm` from a core dump with gdb?

Tags: linux, gdb, core-dump, thread

I wrote a C program that uses multiple threads.
For convenience I set the threads `comm` to some individual value for each thread, and that even might change depending on the state of the thread (a bit like classic `sendmail` always did).

Now when my process dumps core during termination, I see (for example) that there are two threads active when the process failed (one thread is faulting in `pthread_join`).
Unfortunately it's not that easy to find out which thread is which, and the code optimized by gcc usually has a "collapsed stack frame", so the call hierarchy isn't really visible in gcc's backtrace.

Furthermore the problem is very hard to reproduce, so I'd like to get most out from the core dump.

Specifically: Can I display the `comm` field for a thread with gcc?